# I want to create a React App (website) with basic authentication

Tags: reactjs, api, authentication

I want to create a React Application (website) login page with *basic authentication* (username and password) but **NO** registration, **ONLY** login with a **'** private database **'** that redirects to a private route. Is this possible?

(e.g - predefined users with name 'John' and password 'PasswordJohn' and user 'Jane' with password 'PasswordJane')

Like a private API or something?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the .NET Core sdk you can do something like

```
dotnet new react auth=au
```

It will give you a template for login/logout etc.  It hooks up to Azure but you can change the code to use a database or hard code username/password.